# Dynamically update python plot for realtime visualization

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

I am a graduate student with only limited knowledge of the Python programming language. I am currently working on creating a streaming visualization of EEG data. I am able to generate the individual topographical figures using matplotlib, but cannot find a way of dynamically updating a single plot in the output at specific intervals.

Is there some way of taking a list of Figure objects and dynamically displaying each one in turn after some interval in python 2.7? Perhaps using a Graphics object similar to the ones found in Java's Swing? Or would it be better simply to save my plots as images and use JavaScript to display them as desired?

Thank you in advance for any help or suggestions you may offer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make an animation with Python, then there are plenty of ways. For example:
https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/

http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/double_pendulum_animated.html

http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/dynamic_image2.html